# Order of `shift` execution in Perl equation

Tags: perl

For a demonstration of my question, consider the following Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = (1, 2);
my %h;

sub test {
  $h{shift @_} = shift;
}

&test(@a);
print Dumper(%h);
```

The output **IS** as the following:

> $VAR1 = '2';
>
> $VAR2 = 1;

---

Why Perl executes the first `shift` from right side of the equation, and not from the left one?

Why the output **IS NOT** as the following?

> $VAR1 = '1';
>
> $VAR2 = 2;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most language, operand evaluation order is undefined or at least undocumented for most operators.<sup>[1]</sup> Perl is no exception.

Does `f() + g()` call `f()` or `g()` first? Well, that's undocumented and presumably undefined.

---

Now, it turns out that `perl` is currently very consistent. The binary arithmetic operators will always evaluate their left-hand side operand before their right-hand side operand (including `**`, which is right-associative), while the scalar assignment operator and list assignment operator evaluate their RHS operand before their LHS operand.

---

1. Notable exceptions include the comma operator in scalar context, and short-circuiting operators.

   The comma operator in scalar context is documented to evaluate its LHS before its RHS, though no such guarantee is made when it's called in list context.

   Short-circuiting operators —namely `&&`, `||`, `and`, `or` and the conditional operator— must necessarily evaluate their LHS before any other operand.

Comment: And that is a major problem here. Since it is undocumented, in future it can change and then the code that is working now one way will work then differently.

Comment: It could already be changing from computer to computer or even from run to run. (It doesn't, but it could.) You should avoid both reading and modifying a variable in an expression.